# Regex to turn embedded images in to attachments

Tags: images, attachments, mysql, regex

I've got [a blog](http://www.rustyrambles.com/) that has all images **embedded in each post** rather than a **thumbnail linking to an attachment page** which is what I'd like.

I understand from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63126/re-process-images) that no plugin (like [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)) can help me here, I need a regex to swap out all instances in my database and replace with the WordPress default embed method (thumbnail linking to attachment page which links to the high-res version).